# Symfony 2 Twig |date() not working?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.2

i have a little problem and I really don't know why. I am printing a datetime variable in twig with |date() but it is allways printing the actual time.

for Debugging I put the following Code in my Template:

```
<pre>
{% debug entity.getCreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") %}
{% debug entity.getCreatedAt|raw %}
{% debug entity.CreatedAt|raw %}
{% debug entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") %}
```

My Variable is called CreatedAt so normally I should get the correct output with entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s"), right?

My Debug output is as follows:

```
string '16.01.2013 13:46:03' (length=19) //entity.getCreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s")

object(DateTime)[4611] //entity.getCreatedAt|raw
 public 'date' => string '2013-01-16 13:46:03' (length=19)
 public 'timezone_type' => int 3
 public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)

object(DateTime)[4938] //entity.CreatedAt|raw
 public 'date' => string '2013-02-20 21:46:53' (length=19)
 public 'timezone_type' => int 3
 public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Berlin' (length=13)

string '20.02.2013 21:46:53' (length=19) //entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s")
```

I don't understand why it is NULL as soon as I call CreatedAt. And OUTSIDE of the debug tag it is ALLWAYS NULL, not depending on the writing.

In my Entity I've got:

```
private $CreatedAt;

public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->CreatedAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->CreatedAt;
}
```

And in the YML I've got:

```
CreatedAt:
  type: datetime
  nullable: true
```

Does anybody see a mistake?? I really don't find it, maybe it is a bug?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the same result using `{{ entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") }}`?

Comment: I have tested and really can't reproduce...Do you get the same result using [dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) instead of `{% debug %}?

Comment: Hello Cheesemacfly, i solved my problem today - and it was a really stupid mistake! I had a prePersist Class called CreatedAt() and Twig was of course calling it - and recieving NULL.. so i renamed my prePersist class to prePersist() and now it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access your **private** variable `$CreatedAt` outside your entity class, you have to call the **public** getter method `getCreatedAt()` (that's what it's here for).

And in your twig template, when you call `{% debug entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") %}`, since `entity.CreatedAt` is `NULL`, the returned string is based on a new date object:

> If the value passed to the date filter is null, it will return the current date by default.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned by @insertusernamehere, twig automatically calls the public getter.
But this behavior seems to happen only when using the delimiters `{{ }}` over `{% %}`.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#synopsis

Comment: Actually Twig will call the getter method for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i also tried it with public $createdAt, but it doesn't change this behaviour. And the most interesting thing I think is that in {% debug entity.getcreatedat|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") %} I get the right result, but without debug I get NULL... that is what I really don't understand

Comment: @insertusernamehere At first I agreed with you but are you sure that this is the case when the object is access between `{% %}` instead of `{{ }}`?

Comment: It seems you've been right. Added public to CreatedAt and print it with entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") and it is working now. But for Example I also got a string "private $PersonGender;" and this one is also printing in private mode, only with the datetime I needed the public. Maybe that is because it needs to do some ->format() work on the public method?

Comment: If you use `{{ entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") }}` don't you get the expected result?

Comment: Yes, but only as long as it is public. All other variables used are still private and are working, only needed to change all DateTime variables.

Comment: This is really weird because as @insertusernamehere said, Twig calls the getter for you...

Comment: So maybe it is really a bug?

Comment: Sorry guys I was away a few minutes - what's the conclusion?

Comment: If i turn CreatedAt to public and call {{ entity.CreatedAt|date("d.m.Y H:i:s") }} it is working, little bit strange I think, but fine :-)

Comment: @insertusernamehere my conclusion was you were right but it is the case only when using `{{ }}` and not `{% %}` but I can't find anything in the documentation about this...

Comment: I have updated my answer but I will run some tests later to confirm this is true! But still strange :)

Comment: But @cheesemacfly I only used the {% %} tags for demonstration, now I am using {{ }} and still need the public

Comment: @Tny definitely weird...I will run some tests later (probably tomorrow) and see if I can reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP member functions are case insensitive and class members are case sensitive. So `getCreatedAt` will work as good as `getcreatedat` but `CreatedAt` differs from `createdat`.

Here are some further informations about that: [Why are functions and methods in PHP case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749781/1456376).

Comment: Hello insertusernamehere, yes I know about case-sensitive, just did this for showing my error. Please have a look at the example above, i will update it in a second.