# Difference between <?PHP and <?php

Tags: php

I know that the lower-case `<?php`-Tag is the right way.

But i have a application where all `<?PHP` opening tags a upper-case. On our local server and our online Webserver the upper-case opening tags are working well. But on our Test Webserver we had a Issue with that. The PHP interpreter is ignoring everything between the tags.

I know i can simply run a search and replace script to change the tags. But i want to know why this happend. Can anyone help?

P.S. the test system and the online system are identical.

Comment: PHP is case insensitive (sometimes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749781/why-are-functions-and-methods-in-php-case-insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no difference. how  Sergiu Paraschiv says the tag php is case insensitivi. 
Here are the valid ways to open PHP tags

```
<?php ?> // standard tags
<? ?> // short tags, need short_open_tag enabled in php.ini
<% %> // asp tags, need asp_tags enabled in php.ini
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php