# Symfony2/Doctrine Rollback differences

Tags: symfony, transactions, doctrine, try-catch, rollback

I am using Symfony2 and Doctrine for a project and need to do lots of database operations in transactions.

```
try {
    // do db operations
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // rollback here
}
```

My question is the following: Is there a difference between ->rollback() and ->rollBack() ? If there is, what is it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: where did you found `rollback()` and `rollBack()` ?

Comment: Some sites write examples with rollback() but the Doctrine Documentation uses rollBack(), so I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions names in PHP are case-insensitive. If you use `rollback()` or `rollBack()` it results in the same method execution which in this case is `rollBack()`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6302488/1316350).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!